# How to safely dump memory near to a fall inside the SIGSEGV handler. C, Linux

Tags: c, linux, signals, handler, segmentation-fault

I need to print the memory next to the place where the program crashes (SIGSEGV), but the fact is that when I try to print this memory, I can again get called a SIGSEGV.

```
void handler_SIGSEGV(int signal, siginfo_t *data, void *extra_data) {

for (size_t* mem = (size_t*) (data->si_addr - 5); mem < (size_t*) (data->si_addr + 5); mem++){
    printf("%zx\n", *mem);   // call new SIGSEGV
   }

    exit(1);
}
```

As I understood inside the handler, I can use `volatile sig_atomic_t` variables to indicate that the signal has already been triggered.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t isRecall = 0;

void handler_SIGSEGV(int signal, siginfo_t *data, void *extra_data) {

    if (isRecall == 1){
        //second call
    }

    printf("Call - %d\n", isRecall);
    isRecall = 1;
....
```

But when the SIGSEGV signal is called again, my function `handler_SIGSEGV` is not called for some reason.

Why is this happening? And how can I implement such a memory output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`si_addr` is the memory address that generated the fault. Reading the contents may not be possible if the address is out of bounds or the process doesn't have read access. For instance, it may be 0 if a null pointer was dereferenced.

By default, while a signal is being handled, it is blocked, preventing nested calls. Generating a SIGSEGV while it is blocked leads to undefined behavior (usually a crash). From [sigprocmask](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask):

> If SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV are generated while they are
>   blocked, the result is undefined, unless the signal was generated by
>   kill(2), sigqueue(3), or raise(3).

You can continue execution by setting up a `sigsetjmp`/`siglongjmp` pair or modifying the state of the registers (`context->uc_mcontext.gregs`) used by the faulty instruction.